# Distributing PHP-FPM loads among multiple servers

Tags: php, nginx, load-balancing

I run a few web applications (running on NGINX) which causes PHP-FPM to use up a lot of CPU. I was wondering if it was possible to build something like a PHP-FPM "cluster" so that I can add on CPUs to the cluster, rather than having to upgrade the hardware? 
I have got PHP-FPM working on offsite servers before, however, I'm not exactly sure how to "load balance" them.

Comment: We use a cluster of webservers and a separate load balancer running `haproxy`.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I didn't realise haproxy supported fastcgi as well. It seems to be the solution I was looking for. Appreciate your help.

Comment: `haproxy` doesn't care what software is running on the webserver.